# Fiddler and .Net 3.5 SSL error. Works fine in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

First thing, the site and post.

https://saplic.receita.pb.gov.br/sintegra/SINf_ConsultaSintegra.jsp
Fullfil Field CNPJ with value For instance 34151100004209.

Works fine in Chrome and .Net 4.0 Httpwebrequest. But I cant debug in fiddler and cant make it work on .Net 3.5

I'm already using

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateValidation);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

This is driving me insane. Any help will be greatly appreciated
To make things more clear, i'm having one problem that is happening on 2 differente places (Fiddler and .net 3.5)

The code i'm trying to run is.

```
    CookieContainer CookCon =  new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sintegra.receita.pb.gov.br/sintegra/sintegra.asp?estado=pb");
    Request.Timeout = Configuration.TimeOut;
    Request.Proxy = Configuration.Proxy;
    Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36";
    Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    Request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    using (HttpWebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        foreach (Cookie C in Response.Cookies)
        {
            CookCon.Add(C);
        }
        Response.Close();
    }

    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://saplic.receita.pb.gov.br/sintegra/");
    Request.Referer = "http://sintegra.receita.pb.gov.br/sintegra/sintegra.asp?estado=pb";
    Request.Headers.Add("X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id", "C5E5561B-11F5-4D9E-A9D4-54A18E660D11");
    Request.CookieContainer = CookCon;
    Request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
    Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36";

    string HTML = "";

    string Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
    Request.Timeout = 20000;

    Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    using (HttpWebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        Stream S = Response.GetResponseStream();
        if (Response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
        {
            S = new GZipStream(S, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            using (System.IO.StreamReader ResStream = new StreamReader(S, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding)))
            {
                HTML = ResStream.ReadToEnd();
                ResStream.Close();
            }
        }
        else if (Response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
        {
            S = new DeflateStream(S, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            using (System.IO.StreamReader ResStream = new StreamReader(S, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding)))
            {
                HTML = ResStream.ReadToEnd();
                ResStream.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader ResStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding)))
            {
                HTML = ResStream.ReadToEnd();
                ResStream.Close();
            }
        }
        S.Close();
        S.Dispose();
        Response.Close();
    }
```

The error i'm getting is the "unexpeted EOF" excpetion when i try to make the post(GetResponse part of the code above).
If i try to surf the site on Chrome with Fiddler on, it wont return northing, just keeps on hold, hold, hold and nothing.

If I copy the same code to a new 4.0 project, it runs without problem. 
If its not clear, please post the doubts, I'm trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: If it works in .NET 4, but not 3.5, it might be because your SSL certificate has a Subject Alternative Name (SAN, also called "DNS Name"). .NET 3.5 doesn't handle SANs in all cases.

Comment: There is no workaournd for it? Tried to google this SAN thing but got nothing intereseting. Can you explain me more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one helped, i just made a webservice using the .net 4.0 framework and I'm calling it from the 3.5 app.

Still no clue why this happens..